# Multiprocessing for for loops (numpy.ndarray)

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-management, multiprocessing

I'm trying to use the multiprocessing module for Python 2.7 to improve the speed for looping through numpy ndarrays. I'm using an already created matrix 'C' with 6018 rows and 27721 columns in order to compute the PMI matrix. However, I'm getting an "[Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory" when running the following code. I'm assuming the error has to do with the variable PMI, because if I move it into to the pmiCreation function (making PMI a local variable, but I want it to be a global variable, naturally), then the error statement disappears, but the it is of no use since I need the program to remember the updates made to the PMI variable. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

## MAKE MUTUAL INFO MATRIX, PMI

```
print "Creating mutual information matrix"   
PMI = np.zeros((C.shape))     

def pmiCreation(indexStart):                         
    N = C.sum()
    invN = 1/N  # replaced divide by N with multiply by invN in formula below
    row, col = C.shape      
    print "Creating mutual information matrix using indexStart:",indexStart         

    for r in range(row)[indexStart:indexStart+346]:  # u
        for c in range(r):  # w
            if C[r,c]!=0:  # if they co-occur
                num = C[r,c]*invN  # getting number of reviews where u and w co-occur and multiply by invN (numerator)
                denom = (sum(C[:,c])*invN) * (sum(C[r])*invN)
                pmi = log10(num*(1/denom))           
                PMI[r,c] = pmi
                PMI[c,r] = pmi

pool = Pool(processes=8)       # process per core    
index_inputs = [0,346,692,1038,1384, 1730,2166, 2512,2858]    
pool.map(pmiCreation, index_inputs)
```

Comment: You need to specifically define shared memory values between processes - i.e. by passing a `ctype` to multiprocessing.Value https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Could you give an example of how to use the multiprocessing.Value function because I can't really get it to work?